# array vs pointer of char type

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
char label[] = "Single";
char *labelPtr;
labelPtr = label;
cout<<labelPtr;;
return 0;
```

The ouput with the above code is `Single`.
I'am confused about the output.

As far as my understanding `labelPtr` should contain the address of `label[0]`. So shouldn't the output be equivalent to `&label[0]`?

Comment: Have you tried `cout << &label[0];`? What result do you get there?

Comment: Here is a decent explanation of the different behaviours http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: In C++ `char *` is a C-style string, which is basically null terminated array of characters. Therefore it is treated like a string as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::cout treats char* as a pointer to a C-style string.
So the whole C-style string is printed.

Consider casting to (void*) to see what will happen.

Comment: When type casted to `void*`, the address would be printed

Comment: Exactly, but PTA should have checked that on his/her own. It wasn't specified in the question, what result he/she expected to achieve. It was like an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
labelPtr = label;
```

In this label refers to the first element of the char array. And then you are making labelptr point to that same array. That means from now onwards you can use labelptr in a same way you use label.

So, both are equivalent:-

```
cout << label;
cout << labelptr;
```

Comment: *"In this label refers to the first element of the char array."* - Not actually true, rather - when trying to work out how to assign to `labelPtr`, the array to which `array` refers is allowed to undergo a Standard Conversion to generate a `char*` value.  *"you can use labelptr in the same way you use label"* - is not true in general (e.g. you can't call `template <size_t N> void f(char (&)[N]);` with `labelptr`), but is true for streaming to `cout`, but that's because `operator<<(std::ostream&, char*)` is the best match and `label` also decays in that usage....

Comment: Usually when you use just an array name, that means you are referring to base address of that array which means the first element. Secondly, leave cout for a moment and try printf("%s", labelptr) to check what I mean by "you can use labelptr in the same way you use label".Please let me know if there's some indiscrepency.

Comment: "usually" hey?  :-)  Anyway - readers can consider my earlier comment... I've nothing to add.

Answer (score 0):

As `cout` considers the argument to be of type `char*`. All the contents of the string is printed.

For you to print only the first character try using

```
cout<<*labelPtr;;
```

This would print only the first character. To print 2nd character use `cout<< *(labelPtr+1);;`